# How do I fix my induction motor speed control circuit?

Tags: motor-controller, triac

I have designed a speed control circuit for an induction motor. The circuit consists of a zero cross detector circuit whose output pulse is the input to a 555 timer. The 555 timer is used to generate a PWM wave that is then inputted into an optocoupler. The TRIAC control circuit then applies a chopped AC waveform to the induction motor. The **1st picture** is the chopped waveform (incorrect) applied to the motor (used lamp in multisim as there is no motor), the **2nd picture** is how the chopped waveform should look and the **3rd picture** is the circuit diagram. I am having trouble (with the negative half cycle) with getting the waveform in the 1st picture to look like the correct waveform in the 2nd picture. Can you guys please help me fix the design?
[image: 1st picture with partially correct chopped wavform]
[image: Correct chopped waveform]
[image: Circuit Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opto-isolator you are using will not function correctly when the voltage is reversed.

The base-emitter junction of the isolator will break down with only a few volts negative and then drive current into the triac so turning it on and giving the result you are seeing.

Comment: Ah, I see, do you have any suggestions for which optoisolator to use?

Comment: You're looking for an opto-triac instead of an opto-transistor.

Comment: I've tried to replace the MCT6 optoisolator with the MOC8101, however, I get an error when trying to run.

Comment: @Daelin, I get "an error" isn't anything to go on. Edit your question, add in a schematic of your new configuration and details of the error. The MOC8101 is another transistor opto-isolator. Why are you trying to use that?

Comment: @Transistor Apologies, I am fairly new to multisim so I'm not entirely clued up with all the components on there. Do you have any recommendations on which opto-triac I could use?

Comment: Do a search for opto-triac and make sure you don't get a zero-cross type. There are some in the MOC series but I don't know the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I switched out the virtual optocoupler for the MOC8101_BASSO and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Beware, simulated parts don't always have all the characteristics of the real part. MOC8101 has CE breakdown voltage of 30V and EC breakdown voltage of 7.0V. The _real_ part will not handle 230VAC!

Answer (score 0):

A better management of the triac is to control it with a negative power supply and keep the optotransistor.
This way you keep a low voltage driver and control the triac on Q2 and Q3.
It requires to add a wiring to the psu to get the negative voltage but in term of topology robustness, it leads to better results, especially regarding noise immunity, because optitriacs usually suck for dv/dt.